# How can I trigger hover event in slickgrid via javascript

Tags: hover, slickgrid

I'm writing a page where there are many components reside in single frame. In a sense, this is quite similar to concept of Single-Page Application. We have multiple components and slickGrid table is one of them. I'm trying to unify some interaction set into single vocabulary, each of them getting through its own channel.

However, when it comes to highlighting the row, things got complicated. I still haven't figured out the way to activate highlight function in slickgrid to highlight a specific row through javascript. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure which event you're after, but in the slickgrid source code there's a `trigger` function which is used to fire all slickgrid events, which you can use:

```
let trigger = (evt, args, e) => {
  e = e || new Slick.EventData()
  args = args || {}
  args.grid = grid
  return evt.notify(args, e, this.grid)
}
```

use it like:

```
trigger(grid.onMouseEnter, {...})
```

The only missing variable here is `grid`.